Может ли telegram bot получить доступ к камере пользователя напрямую или с помощью Web Apps?
Может ли telegram bot напрямую или с помощью Web Apps получать доступ к камере пользователя в режиме реального времени, если пользователь дал соответствующее разрешение? Например, для создания онлайн-трансляции?
Насколько я знаю, напрямую через telegram bot это сделать невозможно, но с помощью браузера это возможно. И насколько я понимаю Telegram использует свой встроенный браузер, остается открытым вопрос возможно ли с помощью Web Apps взаимодействовать со встроенным браузером telegram чтобы получить доступ к камере смартфона/ПК и осуществить онлайн-трансляцию.
